RAFT in the presence of a network partition disproves CAP Theorem?
RAFT gives consensus, and multiple rounds of consensus gives Linearizability(Strong Consistency).
CAP theorem states you cannot have Consistency in the presence of Network Partitions if you definitely want to have Availability. Yet RAFT being functional even in the face of network faults/partitions seems to be counter-intuitive to CAP Theorem.
What is the loophole in my understanding?
